# Remember the Meta Value With Radio Buttons

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, loop, post-meta

I've created a simple meta box consisting of two radio buttons: yes or no.

When they click on the appropriate box, it saves the meta value to the database. However, the post page does not remember it has done this: whichever radio button was pressed, the 'checked' value is no longer there.

Below is the code. What is the best way to save the 'checked' state — so the user will know which was checked?

```
## ADD TOP META BOX

function top_custom_meta(){
    add_meta_box('top_meta', 'Is this a top post?', 'top_meta_callback', 'post', 'side', 'high');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'top_custom_meta');

## OUTPUTS TOP CONTENT 

function top_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'top_nonce' );
    $top_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); ?>
            <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="top-radio" value="radio-one-a">
            <?php echo 'Yes' ?>
        </label>
            </div>

            <div>
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="top-radio" value="radio-two-b">
             <?php echo 'No' ?>
        </label>
      </div>

    <?php
}

# SAVE TOP OUTPUT TO DATABASE

function top_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'top_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'top_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'top-radio' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'top-radio', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'top-radio' ] ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'top_meta_save' );
```

I basically need to add `checked="checked"` to whichever radio button was pressed.

Comment: This guide will show you exactly what you need. See the Radio buttons sections, it's really well explained. http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/

Answer (score 1):

WP provides [`checked()`](http://queryposts.com/function/checked/) helper to be used in forms. For every choice you need to call it providing current (saved) state and value of current choice. From that it will produce checked markup for the match.